# Sending a Message from a iPhone to a Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, wifi

How would I send a message to an App on my mac (which I develop) from my iPhone via WiFi?
This message would then make something happen in the Mac App.

This is just a fun app for myself so it **doesn't** need any security like SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into a tutorial on Bonjour.

http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxviii-bonjour-and-how-do-you-do

Answer (score 0):

Use TCP to create a connection. Here's a tutorial: http://dev.im.ethz.ch/wiki/Socket_communication_on_the_iPhone

But TCP is extremely common protocol, so on the Mac side you can probably just read up on TCP sockets and be fine.